# What is required to write a program to form your own IP packets?

Tags: sockets, networking, linux-kernel, packet

I am trying to write my own packet crafting software and I would ideally like to do it without any external libraries except what is built on the operating system...

Normally we can create sockets and networked programming with tutorials like this...http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

My question though is I would like to have more control over the actual packets that are sent out. (to prevent OS fingerprinting and to do penetration testing)

Where is the best place to start. Let's assume for now we are in a Linux environment.

Comment: You must study how to make a protocol and a lot of RFC to acquire that you need. Is not a question-answer expected in SO

Comment: You would still use standard socket API practices, the only thing different is that you must use a `RAW` socket (however, most platforms restrict access to `RAW` sockets to admin users only), then you can send your own packet headers, and have access to the headers of received packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of ways for achieving this. It can be done by either raw sockets or by direct access to network adapter kernel mode driver.

Raw socket has traditionally been the choice by many for crafting user defined protocols/packets & for injection tests.

For using raw sockets, you need to select a system that provides access and usage of raw sockets.

Typical steps in raw socket programming shall be as below :

1. Ensure that the process used for crafting your own packet has CAP_NET_RAW enabled
2. Open the raw socket (Use SOCK_RAW)
3. Create your desired packet (Incase if you are building with TCP/IP, ensure to fill appropriate checksum else the packet will be dropped in next node)
4. Ensure to set IP_HDRINCL via setsockopt so that the kernel is aware of presence of header and does not insert its own header. (This also ensures to fill IP checksum incase if it is set as zero.)
5. Send out the data via sendto

However, note that though linux does not fill in any header fill except for scenarios where IP_HDRINCL is present(even here, it will fill only selective fields that are 0), different operating systems will operate differently. So, normally raw socket usage shall reduce feasibility of portability.

Answer (score 2):

Best place to start is probably `man 7 raw` or `man 7 packet`. Creating raw packets should be straightforward; but you will have to implement CRC generation (mandatory for TCP, optional for UDP) and the routing (--> correct interface) by yourself.